# Change checkbox default value before sending

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

This is small problem I am facing. I am printing a checkbox list in which they are checked if the JSON value coming inside them is true and unchecked if JSON value is false.
 So if the checkbox is checked the line of html is

```
<input id="to_be_shown_individually" type="checkbox" ${(this.to_be_shown_individually && 'checked')} value=> <br>
```

Now , i have given option to user to check and uncheck chekbox .  So when they uncheck the checkbox its value remains true always.
See this image in first as chekbox are checked so i get true, but in second attempt when i uncheck them i still get true .

so when i use

```
documen.getElementByID("to_be_shown_individually").value;
```

It always says true whther user have unchecked the checkbox

Comment: Note that it should be `document.getElementById()` - but given you state this doesn't shown any errors I assume this is just a typo in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `value` of a checkbox is always available. To determine if it's checked or not you need to use the `checked` property:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var checkbox = document.getElementById("to_be_shown_individually");
  console.log(checkbox.value, checkbox.checked);
})
```

```html
<input id="to_be_shown_individually" type="checkbox" checked value="foobar" />
<button>Get state</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

`document.getElementByID("to_be_shown_individually").value;`

Look for

`document.getElementByID("to_be_shown_individually").checked;`

this will give you a true or false response based on if the checkbox is checked

Comment: No still i am getting true. I think this is because the input line is <input checked>. Maybe this is problem. But your code is still giving me true on uncheckinig the chekbox

Comment: @RitikSingh the `value` of the checkbox is always available in the DOM. You need to read the `checked` state and then use or ignore the value manually.

Answer (score 1):

html

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="chk">
```

javascript code

```
var checked = json value is true;
$("#chk"). prop("checked", checked);
```